# Hiding and managing navbar elements on small screen

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is what my current navbar looks like on big screen:

[image: current]

And this is what it looks like on small screen(phone)

[image: small]

What i would like to happen is, make the U logo on top left disappear and make the "get in touch" get closer with rest of the elements (I used pull-right class to make get in touch move to the right on big screen) and instead of the navbar being in the center, i would like it to be spread 100% horizontally so it's easier to click them

[image: aim]

Here's my code right now:

http://www.bootply.com/G30iN5Ai4u

I tried using the .hidden-xs class to hide the logo but it didn't work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try :
http://www.bootply.com/sGWCci6pBi

use bootstrap utility classes :

- visible-xs-block  : visible only in mobile devices
- visible-sm-block  : visible only in smaller devices like 'tablet'
- visible-md-block  : visible only in medium devices like 'desktop'
- visible-lg-block  : visible only in large devices like 'desktop'

Other examples can be found :
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/8883

@eratzlaff says :

> - Quick Fix or possible work around.
> - hidden-sm hidden-md = visible-lg
> - hidden-sm hidden-lg = visible-md
> - hidden-md hidden-lg = visible-sm

Code example:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-transparent">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="./index.html"><img src="./images/logo.png" class="img-responsive logo"></a>
            </div>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-firstnav">
                    <li><a href="#work">work</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#skills">skills</a></li>
                    <li class="visible-xs-block"><a href="#contact">get in touch</a></li>
                    <li class="pull-right visible-lg-block visible-md-block visible-sm-block"><a href="#contact">get in touch</a>
                </li></ul>
            </div>
        </nav>
```

Comment: I want the navbar-header to disappear on smaller screens but visible and hidden class don't work on it. I want the "get in touch" to not be pulled right on smaller screens

Comment: Oh i see! I thought you accidently added 2 "get in touch"s but it makes sense now! Thanks

Comment: How should i remove the center alignment on smaller screens? I want it to be full width

Comment: be sure to put the check mark when you get the right answer

Comment: Use css media queries to do custom screen manipulations. You have to write your own media queries and it will fix it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/111330/discussion-between-uzer-and-qwfddq).

Answer (score 0):

The HTML code has a non opened div closing tag.

Otherwise the class hidden-xs must be applied to the navbar-header div:

```html
    <nav class="navbar navbar-transparent">
        <div class="container-fluid">
            <div class="navbar-header hidden-xs">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="./index.html"><img src="./images/logo.png" class="img-responsive logo"></a>
            </div>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-firstnav">
                <li><a href="#work">work</a></li>
                <li><a href="#about">about</a></li>
                <li><a href="#skills">skills</a></li>
                <li class="pull-right"><a href="#contact">get in touch</a>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </nav>
```